# Can't update default views' definitions permanently

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I've created a subgrid showing a custom entity *Blopp*. It shows, the records are viewed as supposed to (related ones only) but I was unhappy with the columns' order and size.

So I went to the solution and made the changes. To my surprise, I discovered that they are not shown when I load the *Contact* form.

Before anybody jumps up with joy - the *save* is done, the *publish all* is done, it's the correct view set in the subgrid **and** when I pick a different view in the subgrid and then go back to the manipulated one, it shows as supposed to!

What's up with that? The way we're handling it now, we need to remove the subgrid and recreate it again.

What can be the cause and how do I kill it?

Comment: Are you making the modifications in IE?

Comment: @BlueSam Yesno. I did that with FF but a colleague of mine uses IE.

Comment: And the issue happens with both?

Comment: @BlueSam Yes. The issue seems to be independent of which browser is being used. Why? Got any hints? (Other than switching to a different browser, of course.)

Comment: Can you try this: remove subgrid from the form, publish customizations, add subgrid to the form again, publish customizations?

Comment: Did you clear your cache?  sometimes CRM Pages will cache without you realizing it.

Comment: @JosephDuty Tested on a bunch of different browsers and computers. By definition, the cache must have been empty on a new machine with a new browser. Also tested after explicit cleansing of the cache, as well...

Comment: not that it explains the behavior, but you can do a control.Refresh.  that may cause the view to update itself (I haven't seen this behavior before so I cant confirm this will fix it)